# Image path in Sonata media bundle

Tags: php, symfony, twig, sonata, sonata-media-bundle

I am trying to find the correct way to display an image with sonata media bundle.

```
cdn:
    server:
        path: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads
```

The twig file

```
{% path  user.image, 'big' %} <br>
<img src="{% path  user.image, 'big' %}" alt="image" class="my-4"/>
```

The result

```
C:\XXX\www\XXX\app/../web/uploads/image/0001/01/thumb_2_image_big.png  
image
```

Now if I copy and paste the first link in the browser, it takes me to the image. But if I use it as a path of an image tag, it does not show, as demonstrated.

There is a workaround for that (by modifying cdn path to ../../../../uploads), but I am trying to find a "normal" way.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<img src="{% path user.image, 'reference' %}" ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but same result.

Comment: I`m sorry, but did you clear cache?
Which version of Sonata & Symfony you use?

Comment: According to [documentation](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/3-x/doc/reference/installation.html) remove **kernel.root_dir** from path:
    _path: /web/uploads_

Why did you use %kernel.root_dir% ?

Comment: because it did not work. I get something like http://localhost/web/uploads/image/0001/01/thumb_2_image_big.png ... without the name of the bundle
it should be: http://localhost/"NameOfBundle"/web/uploads/image/0001/01/thumb_2_image_big.png

Comment: and I can't write the name of bundle in config (I think is not a good practice) that's why I am using kernal.root_dir

Comment: Which webserver do you use?